# how to get architecture information on android. (BUILD API is little limited)

Tags: android, gradle

i want to get something like:

architecture: 2x ARM Cortex-A78 @2.40GHZ
6x ARM Cortex-A55  @2.00 GHZ

along with clock speed for each cpu.

architecture: 2x ARM Cortex-A78 @2.40GHZ
6x ARM Cortex-A55  @2.00 GHZ

current BUILD api is little limited. any native implementation examples or library i can use in this case?

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpu-features#the_google_cpu_features_library